# External script for type="text/babel" not working

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, react-dom

Why is an external script for type="text/babel" not working in ReactJS?
I put the index.html and foo.js in the same folder. Nothing show after I open the index.html file with Google Chrome

---

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>ReactJS</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel" src="foo.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="root"></div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

**foo.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello World</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Hi there, have you found the solution? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run a local server.

For example with https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server :

```
npm -g install http-server
cd <path to app>
http-server
```

Then view your page on http://0.0.0.0:8080

There's also instructions for using python or php to run a local server here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server .

Comment: deserves to mention, entering a command above with option "-o": "http-server -o" will run a local server on one hand and open your app in browser immediately on the other hand

Answer (score 1):

Just include the `babel` file before the `main`. It will work as expected.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="./main.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is not a solution.

Comment: This answer is incomplete as it will give a CORS error and the JavaScript code will not load.  A local web server should be run using Python in addition to the code above. Install it, if not available, and run `python3 -m http.server` and go to http://localhost:8000/ in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

lite-server package seems a bit more promising https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server

In comparison to http-server it:

- opens your application immediately in browser
- supports HMR
- supports file-based configuration

installation and usage is pretty straightforward:

1. npm install --global lite-server
2. cd to your folder in terminal and execute lite-server command

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your developer tools in your browser, you should see a message that CORS blocked the request when trying to open `index.html`:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
```

followed by `Reason: CORS request not http`

This happens because the request origin that calls Babel to convert your React code to a browser compatible Javascript code come from a local file, such as `file://`, which triggers the CORS error. In order to avoid this error, your request origin should come from a `http` or `https` origin, which can be achieved by running a local web server. You can read more details about why it happens at [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp)

If you have Python 3 installed, run the following command in the terminal, where you `index.html` is located. If you need help setting Python and the web server, check this [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server):

```
python3 -m http.server
```

This will serve your page at `http://localhost:8000` and by pasting `localhost:8000` into your browser, now it can render your React code correctly.